# Mongoose find and findOne middleware not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose, find, middleware

If have the following schema and middleware hooks, but the `find` and `findOne` hooks are never being called.  The `save` and `update` hooks work as expected.  According to the [Mongoose Middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) documentation, this should be available.

```
// define the schema for our recs model
var recSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  dis: String,  // rec display
  mod: String   // modified date (HAYSTACK FORMAT)
}, {
  strict: false
});

// create the model for recs
var model = recsdb.model('recs', recSchema);

recSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.mod = HDateTime.now(HTimeZone.UTC).toZinc();
  next();
});
recSchema.pre('update', function(next) {
  this.mod = HDateTime.now(HTimeZone.UTC).toZinc();
  next();
});
recSchema.pre('find', function() {
  console.log("Pre Find");
});
recSchema.pre('findOne', function() {
  console.log("Pre Find One");
});
recSchema.post('find', function() {
  console.log("Post Find");
});
recSchema.post('findOne', function() {
  console.log("Post Find One");
});
```

Comment: How do you verify that it doesn't work?

Comment: Which mongoose version do you have?

Comment: Updated from your comment to ensure I was using 4.0.x.  I am now using 4.0.4 and still nothing.  I verified that it doesn't work by executing a find and a findOne and there is no output in the console.

Comment: Can you also present the code that instantiates the `model`? My guess currently is that you do not use the schema where you subscribed to events to create the model. As in robertklep's gist

Comment: Added schema to code above

Comment: @ShawnJacobson, well, you still miss the code of `model` creation, but I can already see that you are binding to events not of the same schema object that you use for making the `model`. Examine robertklep's gist attentively once again. He takes one object of schema and uses it to bind event handlers and then create the `model` to operate data

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste error (late night last night).  Anyway, I discovered the real issue and posted the answer in case it helps anyone in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue ended up being the order of the items.  Apparently you must define the model after setting up the find hooks.  This is not required for the save and update hooks though.

```
// define the schema for our recs model
var recSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  dis: String,  // rec display
  mod: String   // modified date (HAYSTACK FORMAT)
}, {
  strict: false
});

recSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.mod = HDateTime.now(HTimeZone.UTC).toZinc();
  next();
});
recSchema.pre('update', function(next) {
  this.mod = HDateTime.now(HTimeZone.UTC).toZinc();
  next();
});
recSchema.pre('find', function(next) {
  console.log("Pre Find");
  next();
});
recSchema.pre('findOne', function(next) {
  console.log("Pre Find One");
  next();
});
recSchema.post('find', function(doc) {
  console.log("Post Find");
});
recSchema.post('findOne', function(doc) {
  console.log("Post Find One");
});

// create the model for recs
var model = recsdb.model('recs', recSchema);
```

Comment: Yep, if you make changes to the schema after building your model from it and it works, you just got lucky. :)